# Rewrite configuration to HTTPS not working

Tags: apache, tomcat7, centos7, httpd.conf

actually i'm facing some issues with http to https redirect with httpd (apache) on centos 7.
on the application itself i have specified the following URL

```
https://pwm.mywebsitetest.com
```

It is a tomcat application.
You will notice that the location on the `http` is without the `pwmAD`,
is is like thi because if i insert it, when i call the link on a browser bar i get `404` error because the link apears like this.
`https://pwm.mywebsitetest.com/pwmAD/pwmAD/` when it should show only one o the tabs.
Following the conf file,
What is wrong on the code below?

```
    ######### VHOST per PWM HTTP ###########

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsitetest.com
    ServerName pwm.mywebsitetest.com

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/pwm-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/pwm-access_log combinedXForwardedFor env=!dontlog

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/$ https://pwm.mywebsitetest.com [L,R=302]

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests     Off

  <Location "/">
   ProxyPass http://pwm.mywebsitetest.com:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse http://pwm.mywebsitetest.com:8080/
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>

########## VHOST per PWM HTTPS ###########
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsitetest.com
    ServerName pwm.mywebsitetest.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/cert_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/cert_com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/cert_CA_Bundle.pem

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/pwm-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/pwm-access_log combinedXForwardedFor env=!dontlog
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyRequests     Off

        <Location "/">
                ProxyPass  http://pwm.mywebsitetest.com:8080/pwmAD/
                ProxyPassReverse  http://pwm.mywebsitetest.com:8080/pwmAD/
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all http requests to be redirected to https, all you need in your `:80` VirtualHost is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsitetest.com
    ServerName pwm.mywebsitetest.com

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/pwm-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/pwm-access_log combinedXForwardedFor env=!dontlog

    Redirect / https://pwm.mywebsitetest.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work
Error
Self Service Password Reset
Error
HTTP 404
The page you requested could not be found. 

The link contains a double /pwmAD/pwmAD/
which doesn't efectively exsists.
Any idea?

Comment: I don't quite understand: what exactly did you type in your browser address bar? Did you type `http://pwm.mywebsitetest.com/` and it redirected you (and url in address bar changed) to `https://pwm.mywebsitetest.com/pwmAD/pwmAD/`?

Comment: Yes exactly the way you described.

Comment: what happens if you type `https://pwm.mywebsitetest.com/` (with `s`)? Does it redirect in the same way?

Comment: Yes same result.

Comment: Ok, i got the redirect corretly working, 
now how do i get the https redirect evrythin to the defauld login page?
For example if i call `https://pwm.mywebsitetest.com/fakepage` it whould redirect to `https://pwm.mywebsitetest.com/`
i tryied this `RewriteRule /(.*) https://pwm.mywebsitetest.com/pwmAD/ [L,R=302]` But this works only for `http` Any idea?

Comment: You want any page (except `/pwmAD`) to be redirected to /pwmAD?